# how can i get user's calender data with microsoft graph get request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

My main purpose is to get User's calender by single admin access token.
i am trying to get access token by following these steps.

URL :[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenentId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) Body
client_id:client_ID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:client_secretID
grant_type:client_credentials

this give me an access token
but when i change the scope to  scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read
it gives error

URL :[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenentId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) Body
client_id:client_ID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read
client_secret:client_secretID
grant_type:client_credentials

it did not return access token and says
"error": "invalid_scope",

i will be very thankfull if anyone can help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Client Credential Flow you need to specify the Application permission - Calendars.Read and grant admin consent to it. As you are using `scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` this would get all the permissions you specified in the Azure AD App you created. Then it will include the Calendars.Read permission in your access token which would allow to get usier's calendar.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id/UPN}/calendars
```